# How to connect Jenkins to my test folder saved on my C drive?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, ruby

I'm getting the error message below:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Motor Trade
[Motor Trade] $ sh -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins8268766883038519599.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Motor Trade"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:930)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:450)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:730)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:490)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
ERROR: Step ‘Publish Cucumber test result report’ failed: No test reports that matches features/reports.json found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have specified the folder like this in the Build - Execute Shell:

```
pwd
cd C:/GitProjects/"motortrade_customisable"/features
pwd
bundle exec cucumber features/all_pages.feature
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of the project configuration page click on advance,There you will find a text box named "Use custom workspace".
Add your project path to the "Use custom workspace".
Then at the sonar property set `sonar.sources=.`

Done.

Comment: Hi, I have click on Build but it seems just only executing the json report not the actual feature file. How do I build the cucumber feature file?

Comment: In that case you need to add https://github.com/racodond/sonar-gherkin-plugin plugin to analize cucumber files

Comment: I have tried another way by using Build in Shell and is executing the feature file but  is saying: webdriver ie unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 5555.

Comment: I have placed all 3 webdrivers into the Ruby bin folder but does not seem to work.